# execute an automation with an html button

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, developer

I have the following code that executes an automation.

```
<script runat="server">
var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
 var request = api.performItem("Automation", { ObjectID: "6651e0d8-b478-4cba-8164-c5e8fcc37654" }, "start", {});
</script>
```

but the problem is that every time I run the cloud page starts running the automation and I want to add a button that runs this script only when they click on the button.
what I want is to add a button that executes this script only when they click on the button and not every time you run the cloud page, I do not know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty simple, just have an HTML form:

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form
```

and then wrap your script in a conditional:

```javascript
<script runat="server">
  var submit = Platform.Request.GetFormField('submit');
  if (submit == 1) {
    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var request = api.performItem("Automation", { ObjectID: "6651e0d8-b478-4cba-8164-c5e8fcc37654" }, "start", {});
  }
</script>
```

and then that way, it will only run if you submit your form - e.g. click the submit button.

Comment: your answer is just what I needed, thank you very much.

Comment: sorry @Gortonington one last question, is it possible to display a message indicating that the automation is running? –

Comment: You would likely need to use Client-side Javascript and maybe AJAX or similar. You would basically create a separate processing page with your script and conditional. Have the form on submit (via JS) make the AJAX call to your processing page and then use the return from that AJAX call to fill in the response of 'Auto has started' or 'There was an error' etc..

Comment: Does the automation have to be active?